# Cтроки подключения в App.config и Web.config

Tags: c#, git, непрерывная-интеграция

Представим ситуацию:
В Visual Studio есть решение, которое состоит из 3 проектов. В каждом из проектов в файле `app.config` лежит в открытом виде строка подключения базе данных, развернутой в production среде.

Возникла необходимость работать с этим проектом в команде используя VSTS.

Хочу реализовать такой сценарий:
Разработчик синхронизирует себе репозиторий с этим решением, и в файлах `app.config` строки подключения нет, он должен добавить туда строки подключения к своей локальной тестовой базе данных.
После отправки кода обратно в репозиторий, в процессе CI и CD в файлы `app.config` подставляются нужные строки подключения к рабочей базе данных.

Как можно реализовать это?

Comment: VSTS – это https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, оно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> В каждом из проектов в файле app.config лежит в открытом виде строка подключения базе данных, развернутой в production среде.

Звучит опасно. Получается, предоставляя разработчику доступ на чтение репозитория, вы сразу доверяете ему доступ к боевой базе данных. Думаю, что доступ к боевой инфраструктуре нужно максимально ограничивать. Значит, из репозитория это нужно убрать.

Предлагаю перенести ключевые параметры подключения (например, логин и пароль, или токен, или что там ещё может быть) из конфига в переменные окружения.

Очень подробно о пользе такого подхода рассказывается в манифесте [«12-факторное приложение»](https://12factor.net/ru/config)

- Многие CI-серверы умеют хранить такие переменные и инициализировать ими окружение перед запуском вашего приложения. Точно умеют [GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/#secret-variables), [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) и [Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings) (ссылки ведут на документацию по фичам).
- Доступ к просмотру и редактированию секретных переменных при этом будет у пользователей с максимальным уровнем доступа.
- Если не засветить переменные в логе сборки, то они не будут доступны случайному прохожему. Просто не дублируйте в лог команду для подключения к базе.
- Нужно будет также настроить, чтобы  секретные переменные использовались только при деплое кода из вашей релизной ветки.

Программист будет инициализировать окружение сам, можно написать какой-то скрипт ему в помощь.

Comment: Возможно, есть какая-то специфика, связанная с разработкой под Windows, я её плохо знаю. Буду благодарен за любые комментарии и дополнения.

Comment: "предоставляя разработчику доступ на чтение репозитория, вы сразу доверяете ему доступ к боевой базе данных" -- знание, на каком сервере и с каким именем крутится база, не равно доступу к этой самой базе.

Answer (score 4):

Бонусом ко всему сказанному. Есть возможность трансформировать `app.config` (равно как и любой другой файл) при сборке. Такая функциональность есть по умолчанию в проектах WCF сервисов для `web.config`, но её же можно добавить в другие типы проектов.

Схема следующая: есть некий дефолтный пустой `app.config`, рядом с ним лежат дополнительные файлы с названиями `app.Debug.config`, `app.Release.config`, `app.Test.config` и так далее, которые содержат инструкции для трансформации исходного `app.config`. Если предположить, что в CI и CD используются только определённые конфигурации сборки (например, только Release), то можно в `app.Release.config` держать нужный набор настроек для работы с продуктивом. Разработчики же свободно могут править `app.config` локально и работать с Debug конфигурацией (если разработчикам необходимо работать и с Release, можно добавить новую конфигурацию CIRelease, которая будет использоваться только на билдсервере).

Для использования данного подхода не в WCF проекте, нужно совершить несколько махинаций.

Создаём файл `ConfigurationTransform.targets` следующего содержания:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
            $(AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions);
            .dll.config
        </AllowedReferenceRelatedFileExtensions>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ResolveReferencesDependsOn>
            TransformConfig;
            $(ResolveReferencesDependsOn)
        </ResolveReferencesDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="TransformConfig" BeforeTargets="_CopyAppConfigFile" Condition="Exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
        <!--Создаём трансофрмированный app config в промежуточной директории.-->
        <TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
        <!--Сообщаем, что для сборки нужно использовать только что сгенерированный файл.-->
        <ItemGroup>
            <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
            <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
                <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
            </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Кладём файл в папку решения (уровень `.sln`) и подключаем его сразу после `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\ConfigurationTransform.targets" />
```

Можно в принципе подключать данный таск и напрямую в `.csproj` без создания дополнительного файла, но с доп. файлом автоматически решается проблема с наличием нескольких проектов, для которых нужно трансформировать `app.config`.

Пример. Исходный `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Файл трансформации `app.Release.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="ProductionConnectionString" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

В файле трансформаций используется операция `SetAttributes`, которая задаёт атрибуты для узла, который идентифицируется по атрибуту `name` (`xdt:Locator="Match(name)"`). Другие примеры трансформаций [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).

Вуаля, при сборке в конфигурации `ConfigName`, если рядом с `app.config` есть файл `app.ConfigName.config`, он будет использован для трансформации и сборка будет проведена с использованием промежуточного трансформированного файла.

Пример таска [отсюда](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-apply-build-configuration-transformations-on-non-web-projects/).

---

Еще бонусом небольшой лайфхак. Чтобы файлы трансформации в Solution Explorer не занимали много места, их можно показывать как дочерние от главного `app.config`:
[image: Зависимые файлы трансформации в SolutionExplorer]

Для этого в `.csproj` нужно поправить регистрацию файлов трансформации, добавив тэг `DependentUpon`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="App.config" />
  <None Include="App.Release.config">
    <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Вооот, та самая специфика, про которую я подозревал. ))

Comment: Вместо хардкода файла App.config стоило бы использовать @(AppConfigWithTargetPath) - это обеспечит совместимость со сторонними решениями, которые также меняют App.config.

Comment: И еще: указание `BeforeTargets="_CopyAppConfigFile"` избыточно если вы уже указали TransformConfig в свойстве ResolveReferencesDependsOn. Хотя я бы написал по-простому: `BeforeTargets="ResolveReferences"` вместо использования устаревшего механизма DependsOn-свойств.

Comment: Кстати, небольшое уточнение. Если у вас больше двух release-окружений - даже не думайте создавать для каждого отдельную конфигурацию решения со своими трансформациями! Сборка будет очень медленная. Если другие решения для трансформации конфигов уже после сборки решения.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже написал @NickVolynkin держать строки подключения к БД в `App.config` - плохая практика.
Можно создать локальный файл конфигурации, например, `ConnectStrings.config`, в котором хранить строки подключения, и которого не будет в репозитории (для каждого разработчика он свой). Также написать класс-обработчик этой конфигурации, и при создании подключения к БД вызывать методы этого класса.

Answer (score 3):

Строки из `app.config` можно вынести в отдельный файл через атрибут `configSource`.

В файлах web.config пишется что-то вроде этого:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="bin\connectionstrings.config" />
```

В файлах app.config пишем вот так:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connectionstrings.config" />
```

Во все проекты подключаем общий для всех файл `connectionstrings.config` как ссылку и настраиваем его копирование при сборке. В файле проекта должно получиться примерно вот это:

```
<Content Include="..\connectionstrings.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Дальше этот файл можно добавить в `.gitignore`, позволив тем самым каждому разработчику иметь свой вариант этого файла. (Только не забудьте положить рядом файл вроде `connectionstrings.sample.config` чтобы разработчикам не пришлось каждый раз заполнять его с нуля методом проб и ошибок).

При сборке этот файл надо будет генерировать на стороне сборочного сервера. Также можно при релизной сборке применить трансформацию к конфигу, заменив секцию `connectionStrings` целиком.

Comment: Можно, кстати, совместить моё и ваше решение. Хранить переменные скрыто на сервере, там же генерить из них конфиг для деплоя на бой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin угу, так и надо делать по-хорошему

Comment: Кстати, почему я агитирую за конфиги в переменных окружения, а не в файлах: https://12factor.net/config