# Настройка CI/CD для публикации приложения в Azure

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, azure, непрерывная-интеграция, devops

Хочу использовать Visual Studio Team Services для сборки и публикации своего ASP.NET приложения в Azure Web Application. Раньше публиковал с помощью Web Deploy в Visual Studio, и там мой профиль публикации содержал следующие данные:

- Строка подключение к базе SQL Azure
- Параметры для включения аутентификации в Azure AD

Теперь же, когда публикация происходит с помощью CI/CD конвейера, эти параметры не подставляются и приложение публикуется в облако со строкой подключения и параметрами, которые были на локальной машине.

Вопрос: есть ли способ внести в Build Definition эти настройки? Импортировать профиль публикации при развертывании или еще какие-либо способы корректно развернуть приложение в облаке?

Comment: Те самые [Cтроки подключения в App.config и Web.config](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661284/c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-app-config-%d0%b8-web-config)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Тут вопрос немного о другом: как именно это сделать в VSTS

Comment: Я просто для контекста дал ссылку. Вопрос хороший, ответа не знаю )

Comment: CI/CD конвейера. что за конвеер? с помощью чего стартует этот процесс?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в Visual Studio Team Services есть Build Definitions и Release Definitions. Build Definition стартует по триггеру в Git (обновление кода в master-ветке), релиз стартует после успешного окончания сборки

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев там же есть variables. не хотите оттуда считывать параметры нужные?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor есть ссылка на документацию, где приведен пример работы с variables?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев [вот](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables). внимательно посмотрите на https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/ci-cd-part-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы публикуете приложение именно как  Azure Web Application, то вам *не нужно* править конфиги на стадии билда.

1. Вынесите настройки в web.config, в стандартные секции ConnectionStrings и AppSettings. Они должны быть там по умолчанию, но вдруг вы храните из где-то в другом месте.
2. В портале Azure, в секции Application settings для своего приложения - задайте реальные значения для своего приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения из Application settings применяются поверх того, что вписано в web.config, так что вам вообще ничего не придется заменять в процессе сборки и публикации релиза.

Официальная документация по настройкам: [Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).

App settings:

> For .NET apps, these settings are injected into your .NET configuration AppSettings at runtime, overriding existing settings.

Connection strings:

> For .NET apps, these connection strings are injected into your .NET configuration connectionStrings settings at runtime, overriding existing entries where the key equals the linked database name.

---

Кстати, Azure Web Sites умеют автопубликацию из GIT / VSTS, со встроенной поддержкой основных типов студийных проектов, так что может быть вам вообще не нужны билды в VSTS :)

Comment: Этот способ кстати работал для connectionStrings, действительно, но для настроек Azure Active Directory я такой способ не использовал. Сегодня протестирую. От билдов все таки отказаться не получится, нужно кроме самого веб-приложения в том же процессе опубликовать все его WebJobs

Comment: Ура, получилось!

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев стандартный деплоер azure умеет деплоить и web jobs, на основе webjobs-list.json :)